# Merge 2 tuples in Scala 2

Tags: scala, tuples, concatenation

Are there any ways to merge two tuples in Scala 2 that is equivalenet to `++` in Scala 3 [Tuple - Scala3](https://dotty.epfl.ch/api/scala/Tuple.html)

I can do this to concatenate two tuples in Scala 3:

```
val tup1 = (1, 2)
val tup2 = ("a", 6)
val tup3 = tup1 ++ tup2
```

How can I do this in Scala 2

Comment: This is a code smell. Adding tuples does not make much sense

Comment: @SwiftMango if this is a smell it wouldn't be added to Scala 3. There are reasons why we want to do this and why we want to be able to do it generically without resorting to dynamic typing/subtyping. The ability to perform list operation on tuples gives you a list (also known as a HList) with stronger type guarantees . We now know the type of each element and the size of this list at compile time. To perform the same ops on a `List[Any]` instead of a Tuple/HList means that will need to lose these type information.

Comment: @SwiftMango another example (I'm not sure if this is relatable to you but this is very common in Spark code): typed datasets gets weaken by the programmer into untyped dataframes because they couldn't perform generic transformation(eg generically add the same new columns) on any dataset.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with a generic programming library like [Shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless):

```scala
import shapeless.syntax.std.tuple._

object Main extends App {
  val tup = (1, "Two") ++ (3.0, "4", true)
  println(tup) //(1,Two,3.0,4,true)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add an extension method to Tuple2

```
implicit class Tuple2Ops[A0, A1](val tup: Tuple2[A0, A1]) extends AnyVal {
  def ++ [A2, A3](tup: Tuple2[A2, A3]): Tuple4[A0, A1, A2, A3] =
    (this.tup._1, this.tup._2, tup._1, tup._2)
}

(1, 2) ++ (3, 4) // (1, 2, 3, 4)
```